# Pass JSON objects to an action and map to List<object>?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an action method that takes in two different objects.

I am posting JSON to the action using jquery, to do this I put all the properties i want to map to my two objects in the one Json object.
This works correctly and maps to the two objects in my action!

I want to be able to pass Json and map to a list of objects? is this possible in asp .net MVC?

Thanks

UPDATE: Looks like ActionFilters are the way to go here! found this [post](http://blogger.forgottenskies.com/?p=252).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should map to an `object[]` instead of a `List<object>`. This should map when adding an array of JSON objects as argument to your function.

Comment: Thanks! got it working passing an array of single values in Json! when passing a objects within json, its maps the objects as their string representation, strange!